# Combining DMax with Dlookup to find value from last row created

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have an access database that tracks reports numbered in this way:

```
NNN-[two digit site code]-YY0000
```

The “`0000`” is a sequential number assigned as the reports are issued. 
Examples are: `NNN-SD-180001`, `NNN-MA-180002`.

`tbl_NNN` stores the records. 
`NNN_ID` is the column that stores the report numbers.

The report numbers are manually assigned, so we must keep track of the last assigned number to prevent “duplicating” the sequential 0000 number. Since users do not have visibility to the entire table of assigned numbers, they do not know which is the last number assigned. To assist them, their dashboard/form has a label that displays the last number issued. The problem we have is that the label only shows numbers that include the SD site code, MA numbers are not displayed.

My solution was to add a column named “`Date_Created`”, which adds a `=Now()` time stamp whenever a new row/number is created in the table. With the timestamp, I then intended to use `Dmax` to display the report number that corresponds to the last row created, regardless of the report number.

I know what I need is a combination of `DLookup` and `Dmax`, but what I came up with displays

> "#Error"

in the label.

```
=DLookUp("NNN_ID","tbl_NNN","[Date_Created]=" & DMax("[Date_Created]","tbl_NNN"))
```

Am I writing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you must use single quotes (or unreadable expanded double quotes) for the embedded DMax:

```
=DLookUp("NNN_ID","tbl_NNN","[Date_Created] = DMax('[Date_Created]','tbl_NNN')")
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks for correcting the syntax, i am not too familiar with access functions.